# rails select method iterating array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, iteration

I am new at ruby and rails and on my studies I've created this Payment Types array of my Order..

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base

  PAYMENT_TYPES = [{:id => "check", :name => "Check"}, {:id => "credit_card", :name => "Credit card"}, {:id => "purchase_order", :name => "Purchase order"}]
```

and I would like to use this way

```
<%= f.select :pay_type, Order::PAYMENT_TYPES.each {|order| [order.name, order.id]}, :prompt => 'Select a payment method' %>
```

but I'm getting this error

```
undefined method `name' for {:id=>"check", :name=>"Check"}:Hash
```

what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `each` block, the variable `order` is being filled each time with a hash. Therefore you need to access it like a hash with `order[:name]` and `order[:id]` instead of `.name` and `.id`.

**Edit**

Also, for maintainability, you may want to create a separate PaymentType model. This will give you much more power and flexibility. With your current method, what happens if you want to add or remove a payment type later? You'll have to edit the source code. What if you only want certain payment methods to be available for certain transactions?

Comment: thanks vpsz! but tell me which method should I call instead of .each that returns only that array I need like [['check', 'Check], ['credit_card', 'Credit Card']] ??

Comment: Ah, I didn't even notice that error before. You want to use the 'map' method. `each` simply calls the block for every item in the array (like a foreach loop), whereas `map` runs the block on each of the elements then returns an array of the results (basically transforms the array using the function you provide in the block).

Using .each and .map will be like 95% of what you do in RoR.